# Mosquitto on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm stuck to install Mosquitto on Raspberry Pi - I installed it with:

```
aptitude install mosquitto mosquitto-clients python-mosquitto libmodule-pluggable-perl
```

This is my Config:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_timestamp true 
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd


listener 1883 127.0.0.1 
listener 8883


log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Log shows that the service is up & running:

```
* mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto)    Active: active (exited) since So 2016-10-30 22:20:56 CET; 10s ago   
Process: 2065 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mosquitto stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   
Process: 2071 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Okt 30 22:20:56 elfriede mosquitto[2071]: Starting network daemon:: mosquitto. 
Okt 30 22:20:56 elfriede systemd[1]: Started LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker.
```

netstat -an | grep 1883 shows nothing and the port is not listening. Any hints? What went wrong?

Comment: Check if it's actually running by using `ps -efc | grep mosquitto` Also stop the service and run it manually to check the config file with `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a problem with the mosquitto.conf (No access to the log folder)

Answer (score -2):

If `netstat -an| grep 1883` shows nothing then mosquitto may not be running because 1883 is configured as a listener of your mosquitto broker configuration file.
Please check also theres a mosquitto process running `ps aux|grep mosquitto` so you can confirm whether mosquitto is running or not.
Try `sudo service mosquitto status` also to check mosquitto service status.

Better to run `killall -9 mosquitto` to kill mosquitto process if its running.

You can execute `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosuitto.conf` to run mosquitto if its not running. Here path to your config file can be used. You can run mosquitto as a daemon process by `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosuitto.conf -d`